# C# : Multidimensional array facade?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I have the following classes:

```
public class Layer
{
    public Tile[,] Grid; //50x50 positions filled with my own Tile struct
}

public class Level
{
    public Layer[] Layers; //An array of layers in the level
    public List<object> Objects; //And a couple of lists of say, characters or such in the level.
}

public class Area
{
    private Level[,] _activeLevels; //3x3 array of the current level and surrounding ones.
}
```

What I want is to be able to call for instance..

```
Area.Layers[0].Grid[112, 64];
```

To get the Tile in Grid[12, 14] from Level[2,1].

More explanation:

Assuming a layer has 50 x 50 positions, I hope the following will explain what I want.

"if I call" => "then I actually want"

```
Area.Layers[0].Grid[0,0] => Area.Level[0,0].Layers[0].Grid[0,0]
Area.Layers[0].Grid[0,10] => Area.Level[0,0].Layers[0].Grid[0,10]
Area.Layers[0].Grid[0,49] => Area.Level[0,0].Layers[0].Grid[0,49]

Area.Layers[0].Grid[0,50] => Area.Level[0,1].Layers[0].Grid[0,0]
Area.Layers[0].Grid[0,60] => Area.Level[0,1].Layers[0].Grid[0,10]

Area.Layers[0].Grid[0,112] => Area.Level[0,2].Layers[0].Grid[0,12]
```

--[next part already answered, see below]--

---

Also, I want to be able to call for instance..

```
foreach (object o in Area.Objects)
      //dostuff
```

To call a foreach on -all- the objects from the nine levels.

---

Could anyone give me a nudge in the right direction, some advice on how to achieve this, or heck, plainly code it out?

Comment: I am not able to understand what are you saying.Can you give some idea in pictorial form?

Comment: What I seek is being able to "automatically" translate 'coordinate' Area.Layer.Grid[112, 64] to Level[3, 2].Layer.Grid[12,14].

They are currently not exposed because I don't know how to achieve this result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `Area.Layers[0].Grid[112, 64]` you'd probably be better off with a method of the form `Area.GetTile(0, 112, 64)` implemented as

```
public Tile GetTile(int layer, int overallX, int overallY)
{
    return _activeLevels[overallX / 50, overallY / 50]
            .Layers[layer]
            .Grid[overallX % 50, overallY % 50];
}
```

Comment: I think this will achieve what I want. Thank you for telling me that a method is probably a better way.

Comment: You _could_ set your classes up to work with square-brackets notation like you wanted, but you'd have to create one or two classes specifically to do it; if the method syntax is also acceptable, it's definitely simpler.

Comment: This syntax is also acceptable. How would it be achieved with square-brackets though? Don't bother if its too much of a hassle, but learning new things is always good.

Comment: The construct you're after is an indexer - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx. You'd give `Area` a property called `Layers`, which would return a new class called e.g. `FullLayerCollection`. This class would have an indexer returning another new class called e.g. `FullLayer`. This class would have a two-dimensional indexer returning a `Tile`. This indexer would have to call back up to the parent `Area` an essentially call the `GetTile` method above to work out which `Tile` object to return anyway.

Comment: ... and actually I've missed out the extra class required to let you type `.Grid` between the first and second sets of square brackets. Basically, in this case it'd be more trouble than it's worth, I think. although indexers in general are useful.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want in the first example, you may want to check it's correct.

You can loop over all the objects in 1 iterator by implementing your own IEnumerable:

```
public class Area {
        private Level[,] _activeLevels; //3x3 array of the current level and surrounding ones.

        IEnumerable<object> Objects {
            get {
                foreach (Level lvl in _activeLevels)
                    foreach (object o in lvl.Objects)
                        yield return o;

            }
        }
    }
```

Can the same object be share dbetween different levels? in that case you may want to filter for duplicates.

Comment: Thank you, this (partially) answers my question. I had not thought of being able to provide a getter in such a way.